# Codelgniter Form Validation Showed double repeated form after validate

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-2

Tried to read though all the webpages and docs in google and stack flow but still could not solve the problem.

I tried to do a simple data validation for registration form and it turns out showing another form below the original one after I press submit to show the error messages with a new form.

I am a newbie in this language so please let me know if I attache not enough codes or information.

Controller account:

```
<?php
class Account extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        session_start();
        $this->load->model('user');
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url','html'));
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

    }

    public function registration() {
        $data = $this->user->users_info();
        $this->load->view('account/registration',$data);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password ', 'required|matches[passconf]|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');

        if($this->input->post('submit')) {
            $username= $this->input->post('username');
            $email= $this->input->post('email');
            $query_u= $this->user->retrieve_by_username($username);
            $query_e= $this->user->retrieve_by_email($email);
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $this->load->view('account/registration',$data); ←---------------- (I think this is wrong, it makes load the second form out.)
            }
            else{
                if(!empty($query_u) or !empty($query_e)) {
                    redirect('account/registrat');
                }
                else {
                    $data = array(
                    'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
                    'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                    'password'=>$this->input->post('password'),
                    'is_admin'=>0,
                    );
                    $this->user->create_user($data);
                    redirect('/account/login');
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

View Registration.php

```
<center>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('account/registration'); ?>
<h5><?php echo $b_username;?> &nbsp;(Minimum 5 characters)</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" /><?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
<h5><?php echo $b_email;?></h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" size="50" />
<?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
<h5><?php echo $b_password;?> &nbsp;(Minimum 5 characters)</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" size="50" />
<?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
<h5><?php echo $b_passconf;?></h5>
<input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />
<?php echo form_error('passconf'); ?>
<h5></h5>
<div><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit') ?></div>
</center>
```

Model user.php

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    function users_info() {
        $data['b_id']    =  'id';
        $data['b_username'] = 'Username';
        $data['b_email'] = 'Email';
        $data['b_password'] =    'Password';
        $data['b_passconf'] =    'Enter Password Again';
        $data['b_is_admin'] = 'Is_admin';
        $data['b_default_privacy'] = 'Default_privacy';
        $data['b_first_name'] = 'First_Name';
        $data['b_last_name'] = 'Last_Name';
        $data['b_gender'] = 'Gender';
        $data['b_birthday'] = 'Birthday';
        $data['b_friend_id'] = 'Friend_id';
        $data['b_weight'] = 'Weight';
        $data['b_height'] = 'Height';
        $data['b_daily_cal_intake'] = 'Daily_calorie_intake';
        $data['b_target_weight'] = 'Target_weight';
        $data['b_regional_id'] = 'Region';
        $data['b_profile_pic'] = 'Profile Picture';
        return $data;
    }
    function retrieve_by_username($username) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('001_users',array('username'=>$username));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    function retrieve_by_email($email) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('001_users', array('email'=>$email));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to this and try..

```
public function registration() 
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password ', 'required|matches[passconf]|min_length[5]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) // if validation fails for first time and every time when ever condtion is not satisified
    {
        $data = $this->user->users_info();
        $this->load->view('account/registration',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $username= $this->input->post('username');
        $email= $this->input->post('email');
        $query_u= $this->user->retrieve_by_username($username);
        $query_e= $this->user->retrieve_by_email($email);

        if(!empty($query_u) or !empty($query_e)) {
            redirect('account/registrat');
        }
        else {
            $data = array(
                'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'password'=>$this->input->post('password'),
                'is_admin'=>0
            );
            $this->user->create_user($data);
            // send sucess msg here
            redirect('/account/login');
        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: I kind of understand your logic that you want to load the view with  '    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $this->load->view('account/registration',$data);
   }' but where am I suppose to put the '$this->input->post('submit')'?

Comment: It is not required until and unless you have two or more than two submit buttons (update/ insert etc) in same form and form is directed to same function. Here you have one button with only with one function attached to it. So no use of submit button here.